# jquery dom resizable draggable containment issue

Tags: jquery, resizable, containment

Why is jquery resizable() not resizing to full width and height of the containment id assigned to it. You can try it at http://jsfiddle.net/C8YSU/6/ and see what i mean. Try to resize the created div, it will not resize to full width and height on the parent #container div. This seems to be caused by the `draggable()` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding a relative position to the #container div fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("button").click(function () {
            var elm = $('<div id="divId" class="adiv abs"></div>');
            elm.appendTo('#container').resizable({
                containment: "parent"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Update**

```
<script>
        $("button").click(function () {
            var elm = $('<div id="divId" class="adiv abs"></div>');
            elm.appendTo('#container').draggable({
                snap: true,
                containment: 'parent'
            }).resizable({
                maxWidth: 300,
                maxHeight: 300
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: parent doesn't work, already discussed below. You also got rid of draggable which is needed. Please read all replies before answering. I already gave the working answer below.

Comment: Thanks @jhanifen for voting. Whereas @Alex solution also works, if you add position relative to #container, it works

Comment: his code works because he removed the draggable(). We want to keep draggable.

Comment: setting max width and max height is not the right way of doing it. Just position the container div relative as i mentioned in my answer below and it's done.

Comment: Works for me (similar problem, `snap: true` fixes it though, despite that it's slightly different)

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with adding draggable to it.

Try this example.  Removed draggable, but added handles.

http://jsfiddle.net/C8YSU/7/

Comment: I need both draggable and resizable.

Comment: I tried changing the containment to 'parent', this did not fix the problem either.